# NodeJS, sqlite3, and WHERE IN paramaters

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

Does the [`sqlite3` library for NodeJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) support parameters for `WHERE IN` queries?

I have the following small program.

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
const db = new sqlite3.Database('./data/data.db');

const sql = `
    SELECT * FROM accounts
    WHERE
        name IN ('Business Expense - Internet Service','RCSB Checking')`;

db.all( sql,
        function getAccout(error, rows) {
            console.log(error);
            console.log(rows);
        });
```

The program "works".  It queries the database, and the `rows` variable is successfully populated with data from two separate rows.

However, I don't want hard coded values.  I want to parameterize my values.  The following code works for that.

```
const sql = `
    SELECT * FROM accounts
    WHERE
        name = ? OR name = ?`;

db.all( sql,
        ['Business Expense - Internet Service','RCSB Checking'],
        function getAccout(error, rows) {
            console.log(error);
            console.log(rows);
        });
```

However, I want this to work with *any* number of names.  i.e. I want to parameterize the original `WHERE IN` query.  However, the following program

```
const sql = `
    SELECT * FROM accounts
    WHERE
        name IN (?)`;

db.all( sql,
        [['Business Expense - Internet Service','RCSB Checking']],
        function getAccout(error, rows) {
            console.log(error);
            console.log(rows);
        });
```

does not work.  It runs without error, but returns zero rows.  I also tried using a concatenated string as the param

```
const sql = `
    SELECT * FROM accounts
    WHERE
        name IN (?)`;

db.all( sql,
        ["'Business Expense - Internet Service','RCSB Checking'"],
        function getAccout(error, rows) {
            console.log(error);
            console.log(rows);
        });
```

and this also didn't work.

Does the `sqlite3` library support parameterizing `WHERE IN` queries?  If so, what's the syntax for doing so?  If not, are there common work arounds to this in the NodeJS community?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is support for it, but in case there is not

```
const params = [...]
const sql = `
    SELECT * FROM accounts
    WHERE
        name IN (${new Array(params.length).fill('?').join(',')})`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest using JS string literals as well. Seems more like the 'node way' of doing things.